# Hyperbolic p-norm

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

> The $1-$norm in Euclidean geometry is $d_{geometric}(u,v)=\| u-v \|_1$.
> We can convert this in hyperbolic space using a **Poincare disk model** by:

> $$ d_{hyperbolic}(u,v) = \operatorname{arcosh}\left( 1+ 2 \frac{\|u-v\|^2}{(1-\|u\|)^2(1-\|v\|)^2}\right) $$

***My question:*** Can i generalise to $p$ dimensions as simply as:

$$ \|u-v\|_p =\operatorname{arcosh}\left( 1+ 2 \frac{\|u-v\|^2_p}{(1-\|u\|_p)^2(1-\|v\|_p)^2}\right)? $$

Furthermore, if the property does hold, then I assume it is also scalar invariant? i.e to convert $K \times d_{geometric}(u,v)$, we just write  $K\times d_{hyperbolic}(u,v)$?

Comment: What is a motivation for this?

Comment: @Berci Graph Neural Networks are better suited to hyperbolic space, so I want to extend it to high dimensions

Comment: "Can I generalize..." is not strictly a mathematical criterion. (i) The expression is _defined_ on the open unit ball in arbitrary dimension; (ii) It's not obvious (to me) the expression satisfies the triangle inequality; (iii) It's not obvious there's a natural geometric sense in which the proposed function "extends" the hyperbolic metric. <> By contrast, omitting the $p$ (assuming the original formula is OK) appears to give the hyperbolic metric in arbitrary dimension. <> IIRC, the $1$-norm is not the Euclidean norm in the plane, and I may be interpreting "dimension" differently than you.